Is there a way to prevent multiple clients from reading and processing the same data multiple times?
Looking at using Cassandra for a time-series, non structured and structured data in an environment with Kafka, Sparc etc. Have a scenario where multiple gateways at sensor installation sites are listening to the sensors- and reporting the data back. Multiple gateways could be sending the same data published by the same sensors- if they have overlapping ranges. Assuming all of these are stored in Cassandra as they come, while reading the data, especially with microservice oriented multiple threads, avoid reading and reacting to the same sensor data multiple times? New to Cassandra- so if this question is naive, apologize beforehand.
Let me explain the scenario further; We have data in cassandra (how it comes is immaterial).  While reading and processing the data, we may have to send notifications/alerts depending on the specific values of the data. Hence each data should be read only once. There are multiple parallel processes are running which are reading and processing the data.  So how do we make sure that each data is read only once by one of the processes? (If not, multiple alerts will go- which should be avoided).

Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's not clear to me exactly what problem you're trying to solve. It would be ideal if you could provide examples of the data and example app queries. Cheers!

Thanks Eric. Let me try and simplify the question: Say we have data d1, d2, d3,... upto d10. And we have processes (Services) p1, p2, p3... etc. All services are reading in parallel. Want to make sure d1 is read just by one of the processes (any one). What is the best way of doing it?

Sorry, I still need more info. What are you trying to achieve? Also, a friendly request to please update your original question directly with the additional info to make it complete. Cheers1

I have just expanded the original question- thanks a lot.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Cassandra is designed for high velocity, high throughput performance with millions of concurrent access at internet scale. This is one of the top reasons you choose it for your use case so it doesn't make sense that you want to limit reads to a single client.
Based on your description, it sounds like you are using Cassandra as a queue for processing data and this is an anti-pattern because queue-like datasets tend to generate a lot of tombstones and is not a good fit for Cassandra.
For more info, see Cassandra Anti-Patterns: Queues and Queue-like Datasets. Cheers!
